# How can I validate incoming request in Apache CXF web framework

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am now to webservice and I need to do input request validation in apache cxf webservice.

Can anyone let me know different ways to do so

Comment: What you have done some far. Please post those code snippet. One liner questions will not help to understand what is the problem. For instance, you have not mentioned if its REST or SOAP.

Comment: You can use bean validation: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/validationfeature.html